# Reading a session variable inside a behavior in cakephp 2

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a behavior which enables segregation of user data based on the user id stored in the session.  In CakePHP 1.3 you could do this:

```
App::import('Component', 'Session');
$session = new SessionComponent();
$session->read('Auth.User.id');
```

But in CakePHP 2, you can't instantiate a component like that in a behavior because the Component __construct requires the Controller's ComponentCollection as a parameter.

Is it possible to access a session variable inside a behavior in CakePHP 2?  What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you look at the `SessionComponent` code, you will see that it is only a wrapper for the `CakeSession` class.

So you can do the following:

```
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
$user_id = CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id');
```

Comment: Nice catch.. clearly wasn't thinking too hard when I posted this last night.

Answer (score 3):

In CakePHP 2.0 you can also simply call the Session-methods via the static CakeSession::method() without having to load *anything*... ;-)

Comment: well, your class should still have the `App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');` statement, though! ;)