# Why is session data only available in the controller in CakePHP?

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

So, I like CakePHP and use it lots.  When 2.0 came out, I was pleased to see the AuthComponent be made available throughout your whole application as a static class, which makes lots of things much easier - i.e. you no longer have to pass user data as an argument to model methods.

Recently on a project, I have perceived the need to access methods of the SessionComponent from a Model.  Specifically, when a user logs in, some checks are performed to see if the user has a valid subscription to the site.  This is all done in the model.  If the user no longer has a valid subscription, there are a few reasons why that might be.  It seems easiest to return `false` from the model, and at the same time set a flash message giving the reason for the expired subscription.  Rather than return an array  something like this:

```
array('status' => 0, 'message' => 'You\'re not welcome here anymore')
```

which needs interpreting in the controller.

There are other times I have wanted to deal with sessions in models, but this is the example that came to mind.

So, I'd like to know, am I right in wanting to access the SessionComponent in models?  Should I just use $_SESSION directly when I have this need?  Or am I doing things wrong - are there better ways to code?

Answer (score 2):

you can always use

```
CakeSession::read()
```

anywhere in your application. so also in the model.
see previous posts like [Reading a session variable inside a behavior in cakephp 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529199/reading-a-session-variable-inside-a-behavior-in-cakephp-2)

but be adviced, that you should try to avoid it if possible.
models are supposed to be as stateless as possible - mixing them with sessions makes that more  and more blurry.

Answer (score 1):

According to CakePHP [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html):

> Usage of the $_SESSION is generally avoided in CakePHP, and instead
>   usage of the Session classes is preferred.

There are several different configurations where you can store session data, f.ex. in the database. So, by using `CakeSession` changes to session configuration will not affect every place where you access session data.

I would advice not to use SessionComponent from the model. Better pass parameters to the model with necessary data. Take a look at [Understanding Model-View-Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html).

Answer (score 1):

Passing session control to the Model violates MVC. You should use the model to make the decisions and the controller to reflect those decisions to the application. In a correct MVC enviroment the Model won't even know you are using sessions much less manipulating it.

Also, using the $_SESSION var violates the framework encapsulation. If you find yourself **needing** to do that, yes, you went wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can write and read data in session in model by using `Authcomponent` and `session`

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
App::import('Component', 'Session');
```

and you can write and read data using following functions

```
CakeSession::write('Auth.User.id', '1');
debug(CakeSession::read());
```